# Django 1.6 - reusable view with redirect

Tags: django

I have just made reusable comments app that can be attached to any model, please see view I have problem with ( I didn't include whole logic, only the one relevant to the question).

When there is no request.POST, all is working fine, however when I try to add the comment, after it is saved there is some problem with redirect, I am getting error

```
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required
```

problematic line is context.update(dictionary). It looks like it is empty when comment is added, but I don't understand why.

My logic is this:

1. when there is no request.POST, view add_comment will return
   {'comment_form': comment_form, 'comments': comments}
2. when `request.method==POST'` , `context.update(dictionary)` shouldn't
   be even executed, because of return redirect(node). It should result
   in starting code executing in view profile, because that's where
   redirect(node) should lead to.

I know I could just use redirect in profile.views.py, but then I will need to do this for every view with added comments, which is extremely unconvenient.

comment.views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from comment.forms import AddCommentForm
from comment.models import Comment

def add_comment(request, node):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
    else:
        user = None
        comment_form = None
    comments = Comment.objects.get_comments(node) # custom manager method for getting all comments
    if user:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            comment_form = AddCommentForm(request.POST)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                comment_form.save(node=node, user=user) # custom form save method, updating missing fields
                return redirect(node) #redirect to node.get_absolute_url()
        else:
            comment_form = AddCommentForm()
    return {'comment_form': comment_form, 'comments': comments}
```

profile.views.py - another app, I want to reduce the code for adding comment by only referring to view add_comment

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from comment.views import add_comment

def profile(request, id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    dictionary = add_comment(request, user)
    context = {'user': user}
    context.update(dictionary) #problematic line
    return render(request, 'profile/profile account.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that add_comment can return something that isn't a dictionary: that is, a redirect (which is a subclass of HttpResponse). You could always check the type of what is returned before using it:

```
result = add_comment(request, user)
if not isinstance(result, dict):
    return result
else:
    context.update(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for extremely quick help, now it is working. However I have heard that checking instance type should be used only in the last resort:) I am not experienced in programming yet and that's why I need to learn good practice whenever possible, that is why idea for reusable subview , I always try to avoid duplicated lines, now in every view with attached comments I will  need to check instance type, maybe I could replace function add_comment with counterpart class with some method like dictionary updating? Thanks for your help once more.